# Twig extends doesn't work

Tags: twig

I am trying to set up a new twig workflow for the first time.

I am currently developing on a Mac Book Pro, El Capitan OS using xampp.

I have to twig files: base.twig and index.twig. I want the index to extend the base, so my index looks like this:

```
{% extends 'base.twig' %}

{% block header %}
    <p>hi</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Both files are located in my ../app/Resources/views/ folder but when I inspect my page with the Browser it only returns the content of my base.twig.

This is my base.twig:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    {% block head %}
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Web Project Template</title>
    {% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body>
    {# header #}
    <header class="header header__main">
      {% block header %}
      {% endblock %}
    </header>

    {# content #}
    <main class="content content__main">
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </main>

    {# footer #}
    <footer class="footer footer__main">
      {{ include('../../app/Resources/views/partials/footer.twig') }}
    </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my index.php where I render the templates:

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
/*
 * Go to this file in your web-browser to render Twig templates:
 *
 *  * http://localhost/index.php            -> index.twig
 *  * http://localhost/index.php/contact    -> contact.twig
 *
 * ... etc ...
 */
// 1) create a Symfony Request, used only to help make each URL render a different Twig template
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$uri = $request->getPathInfo();
// 2) bootstrap Twig!
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Adapter(__DIR__.'/');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    // cache disabled, since this is just a testing project
    'cache' => false,
    'debug' => true,
    'strict_variables' => true
));
$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());
// 3) create a few different "pages"
switch ($uri) {
    // The Homepage! (/)
    case '/':
        echo $twig->render('../../app/Resources/views/base.twig', array(
            'pageTitle' => 'Suit Up!',
        ));
        break;
    // All other pages
    default:
        // if we have anything else, render the URL + .twig (e.g. /about -> about.twig)
        $template = substr($uri, 1).'.twig';
        echo $twig->render($template, array(
            'title' => 'Some random page!',
        ));
}

?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a header block in you base?

Answer (score 0):

You have to render the file `index.twig`.
Twig will not search other file that extends your base.

```
[...]
// The Homepage! (/)
    case '/':
        echo $twig->render('../../app/Resources/views/index.twig', array(
            'pageTitle' => 'Suit Up!',
        ));
        break;
[...]
```